# Is it possible to embed a device from AWS device farm on my website

Tags: aws-device-farm

My requirement is to be able to embed the devices I purchase through aws device farm inside my website. The devices will have our mobile app installed in it, and the users would be able to interact with the application via the web.

We have other controls also on our website which directly control the actions in the app, which is why we cannot give the app to the user directly.

Does aws device farm provide that facility?

Comment: This is a bit out-of scope for AWS Device Farm's mobile testing service. The service is not meant to use devices as permanent hosts, but rather provides the infrastructure to continuously test your mobile applications. You can contact aws-devicefarm-support@amazon.com for more information.

Comment: @TobeE Thanks for you response, I sent an email to awsdevice support, yet to hear from them.